# Retrieve value from Store

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have the following store:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.model.MenuPoint', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'string'},
        // this is id of the element, example child id, report id, and so fourth
        //{name: 'elementId', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'icon_url', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'xtype', type: 'string'}
    ]
}
});
```

And I manage to insert and retrieve the value like this:

```
var keyValue = new Object();
keyValue.key = "adultId";
keyValue.value = adultObj.adultId;
console.log("keyValue: "+keyValue);
var sessionStore = Ext.getStore('MySessionStore');
sessionStore.add(keyValue);
sessionStore.sync();

var index = sessionStore.find('key',keyValue.key);
console.log("index: "+index);
var keyValue2 = sessionStore.getAt(index);
console.log("keyValue2: "+keyValue2);
```

But it so cumbersome to first get the index, then get the value, isnt it possible to do something like this:

```
var value = store.get(key);
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use function

```
var record = store.findRecord('id', key)
```

it is a shortcut to

```
index = store.find('id', key);
record = index != -1 ? store.getAt(index) : null;
```

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: Do you have any idea how to get index value , according to tapped.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206412/getting-index-value-0-from-dataview-any-list-itemtap-from-sencha-touch

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
store.findRecord('id', key, 0, false, true, true);
```

By default, findRecord search uses regexp. You should pass all 6 parameters to get expresstion like `===`

Or if you find by "id" try `store.getById(key)`

See [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1a5p)