# getting index value 0 from dataview any list itemtap from sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, dataview

I am unable to get index value form the dataview:

```
    {          
              xtype: 'list', 
              itemId: 'catList',
              store: 'CategoryStore',    

             scrollable: false,
              layout: 'fit',          
              itemHeight: 20,
              itemTpl: [
              '<div>',
              '<tpl for="data">',
              '<span >{category_name}</span> ',             
          '</tpl>',
          '</div>'],
listeners: {
   'itemtap': function(list, index, target, record, e, eOpts){
     console.log(record.get('cat_id'));
}
}
}
```

**Edited:**
If i put data static on store it works fine but it does not work while getting data from server:

**it works like as displayed on list:**

```
      {    
          xtype: 'list', 
          itemId: 'catList',
          scrollable: false,

    data: [
    { category_name: 'A', cat_id: 1},
    { category_name: 'B', cat_id: 2},
    { category_name: 'C', cat_id: 3},
    { category_name: 'D', cat_id: 4},
    { category_name: 'E', cat_id: 5},


    ],
    loadingText: "Loading Words...",
    emptyText: '<div>{message}</div>',
    autoLoad:true,
    itemTpl:[
    '<tpl for=".">',
          '<span >{category_name}</span> ',             
      '</tpl>',
    ] 
  },
```

Here, I tap many times on different row but only gets index 0, why is this? why am i not getting  different index value while tapping different row of list item;

**[My JSON](http://alucio.com.np/trunk/dev/sillydic/admin/api/word/categories/SDSILLYTOKEN/650773253e7f157a93c53d47a866204dedc7c363?_dc=1376475408437&page=1&start=0&limit=25)**

Comment: Can you please give us more info about the kind of data you are trying to show here (such as the json?)

To me it sounds you are showing only one item in which you are iterating many times and display your rows within your span..

Comment: Here, If i tap on category name, then i want to get index value and want to get tapped cat_id help of index. So finally,my intention get data according to cat_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried and working perfectly for me, Let me share what i did.

**Model**

```
Ext.define('Myapp.model.Category', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'cat_id', type: 'integer' },
            { name: 'category_name', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'created_date', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'order', type: 'integer' },
            { name: 'status', type: 'integer' },
            { name: 'deleted', type: 'integer' },
            { name: 'type', type: 'integer' }
        ]
    }
});
```

**Store**

```
Ext.define('Myapp.store.Category', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'Myapp.model.Category'
    ],
    config: {
        storeId: 'category',
         model: "Myapp.model.Category",
         proxy: {
            type: "ajax",
            url : "http://alucio.com.np/trunk/dev/sillydic/admin/api/word/categories/SDSILLYTOKEN/650773253e7f157a93c53d47a866204dedc7c363?_dc=1376475408437&page=1&start=0&limit=25",
            reader: {
                type: "json",
                rootProperty: "data"
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    }

});
```

**List**

```
 {          
    xtype: 'list', 
    itemId: 'catList',
    store: Ext.create('Myapp.store.Category'),
    layout: 'fit',      
    itemHeight: 20,
    itemTpl: [
              '<div>',
              '{category_name}',             
              '</div>'],
            listeners: {
               itemtap: function(list, index, target, record, e, eOpts){
                 console.log(record.get('cat_id'));
            } 
     } 
  }
```

**Output**

[image]

As you can see itemtap function also printing correct cat_id

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment

```
{    
   xtype :'panel',
   items : [{
       xtype : 'toolbar',
       itemId: 'categoryName'  // Give itemId  
      },
      {
       xtype: 'list', 
       itemId: 'catList',
       height : '100%',
       store: Ext.create('GoodNews.store.Category'),
       layout: 'fit',      
       itemHeight: 20,
       itemTpl: [
         '<div>',
         '{category_name}',             
         '</div>'],
         listeners: {
           itemtap: function(list, index, target, record, e, eOpts){
             var catId = record.get('cat_id');
             var categoryName = record.get('category_name');
             // Set the title like this
             this.getParent().getComponent('categoryName').setTitle(categoryName);
           } 
         }                
       }]     

 }
```

Comment: In the same view, if i have toolbar then i want to display tapped category name in toolbar title, How to do this?

Comment: it is the same view, but i want to display, if i click architecture, i want to display another view that architecture in title.

Comment: you said "In the same view", thats why i posted like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what's wrong with your code as I tested it and it worked fine. However, a few things are wrong.

- You do not need the for loop in your itemTpl as "itemTpl" is already
  iterating in you data array for you. You would need it if you were
  using just "tpl".
- Avoid to have your listeners in your view. Instead,
  get a reference to your list in your controller, and set the
  listeners there. **This is bad practise and it breaks the NVC pattern.**

Here is a small version that works on my te4st application:

```
{
    xtype: 'list', 
    itemId: 'catList',
    scrollable: false,
    data: [
        { category_name: 'A', cat_id: 1},
        { category_name: 'B', cat_id: 2},
        { category_name: 'C', cat_id: 3},
        { category_name: 'D', cat_id: 4},
        { category_name: 'E', cat_id: 5},
    ],
    loadingText: "Loading Words...",
    emptyText: '<div>{message}</div>',
    autoLoad:true,
    itemTpl: '{category_name}',   
    listeners: {
        'itemtap': function(list, index, target, record, e, eOpts){
            //TODO: whatever..
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I know this is working, but my problem is, How to get that value from store. see ->>store: 'CategoryStore',   . I want to getting that store. please could you help me how to get from this .

Comment: this is working if i get value from store, i can't get tapped value. if i do this it is working.

Comment: My data display this type, according to JSON: itemTpl: [
          '<div class="categoryListings">',
          '<tpl for="data">',
          '<ul>',
          '<span >{category_name}</span> ',  
          '</ul>'  ,        
      '</tpl>',
      '</div>'], Look at my problem i added MY JSON at end of problem.

Comment: The example I showed you is working with a store or inline data. 
As I said you should have the listeners in your controller.
in the itemtap callback method, "record" is the record from the store, so you can access all properties of that record.
if this is the store that you want, there are two ways
1. Keep a reference of it in your controller, 2. do list.getStore() in your callback method

Comment: I am not using listeners in controller, It is in view. But I am not getting recode.get('cat_id') value. I used this as you earlier say but did get it.temTpl: [
          '<div class="categoryListings">',
          '<tpl for="data">',
          '<ul>',
          '<span >{category_name}</span> ',  
          '</ul>'  ,        
      '</tpl>',
      '</div>'],
    listeners: {
           'itemtap': function(list, index, target, record, e, eOpts){
            console.log(index);  recode.get('cat_id'); }}

Comment: I know you have it in the view. But I'm saying you shouldn't. This is bad practise. 
I don't understand your last comment sorry.

Comment: you said me, I am using listener in controller, but i am not using in controller.watch mod full code.http://pastie.org/8235822

Comment: What should i do, from view and controller. Actually i got every tapped index value 0, i can't fire index value because it goes every time. please explain more with code. Thank you for giving me useful idea.