# Sencha: Use store in other view

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, datastore

I have a store, which is created in  a controller when login is successful. The code looks like this:

controller is login.js

```
    //////////// create a JSONstore and load companies into it ////////////// 
var companies_data = new Ext.data.JsonReader({}, [ 'companyame']);      
    var storeCompanies = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    storeId: 'storeCompanies', 
          proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
              type: 'GET',
            url: url+'dashboard/?Uid='+uid+'&Ude='+ude,
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'root',
                totalProperty: 'total'
            },
            headers: {
               'Accept' : 'application/json;application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
             params: {
                Uid: localStorage.uid,
                Ude: localStorage.ude,
            },
          }),
          reader: companies_data,  
          root: 'd',
          type: 'localstorage',
          autoLoad : true,
          id: 'company_Id',
          scope : this,
          fields: ['companyname']
        });
```

The code is a function, which is called on successful login and values are passed to it.

This works fine for as is, and the store is available to the login view

I need the store to be available to my mainview.

In my login.js controller, I have referred to the mainview like this:

```
Ext.define('axis3.controller.Login', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
config: {
    refs: {
        loginView: loginview,
        mainView: 'mainview',
        chartView: 'chartview'
    },
    control: {
        loginView: {
            signInCommand: 'onSignInCommand'
        },
        mainMenuView: {
            onSignOffCommand: 'onSignOffCommand'
        }
    }
},
```

but this does not seem to help.

When I use the following in my mainview

```
var companyStore = Ext.getStore('storeCompanies'); // 
console.log('1-Number : ' + companyStore.getCount()); // Using getCount method.
var anotherCompany = { companyname: 'North Wells'};
companyStore.add(anotherCompany);  // 
console.log('2-Number : ' + companyStore.getCount()); // Using getCount method.
//////////////

Ext.define('axis3.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
requires: ['Ext.TitleBar','Ext.data.Store'],
alias: 'widget.mainview',......................
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating
>   'companyStore.getCount')

How can I use my store in a different view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If have figured out the problem. The view is trying to use the store before it exists. The store is only created when a user logs in.

The solution I have decided to use is to create an empty store and then add data to it on successful login.

```
var anotherCompany = {companyname: 'Keep Groom'};
companiesStore2.add(anotherCompany);  // Use the add function to add records or model instances.
```

This seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Give `storeId`, try like this

```
var storeCompanies = Ext.create("Ext.data.JsonStore",{
          storeId: 'storeCompanies', // add this line
          proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url+'dashboard/?Uid='+uid+'&Ude='+ude,
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'root',
                totalProperty: 'total'
            },
            headers: {
               'Accept' : 'application/json;application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
             params: {
                Uid: localStorage.uid,
                Ude: localStorage.ude,
            },
          }),
          reader: companies_data,  
          root: 'd',
          type: 'localstorage',
          autoLoad : true,
          id: 'company_Id',
          scope : this,
          fields: ['companyname']
        });
```

Now try again with `Ext.getStore('storeCompanies');`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added the storeID and used Ext.getStore('storeCompanies'); in the view where I need to use the store, but still getting the same error. I have edited my question to show more of the view code

Comment: @JezD did you added storeID or StoreId ?

Comment: storeId: 'storeCompanies': exactly as your suggestion

Comment: Also i am using Ext.Create. did you noted that ?

Comment: @Viswa, I think you are active user of stackoverflow in sencha, so please see my problem, could you give me some idea, How to get index value from list.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206412/getting-index-value-0-from-dataview-any-list-itemtap-from-sencha-touch